# ExtJS Prevent LoadMask from Stealing Focus

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, modal-dialog, focus

I have established my own `Store` class where I can optionally enable "Polling" on the store, which initializes a `TaskRunner` task to `reload()` the `Store` on a defined internal. That is all well and good, however when the `PollingStore` is bound to a `View`, the `LoadMask` will automatically show whenever the `reload()` method is invoked.

This is desirable behavior.... for the most part. My issue is that when the user has another window (e.g., for creating a new product) open "in front" of the grid (in zindex terms). Whenever the `reload()` method is invoked on the `Store`, the now-bound `LoadMask` will appear in front of EVERYTHING, i.e., including the window that the user is currently interacting with, which is separate from the `Grid` associated to the `Store` being loaded.

I have managed to override the `initComponent` method and ensure that the `LoadMask` does not appear "over" other components, but it still manages to steal focus from whatever form fields the user happens to be filling out in the modal window at that time....

Again, breakdown of steps here...

1. Establish a Grid with a connected Store
2. Establish TaskRunner task on Store to reload every 30 seconds
3. While viewing the Grid, open a modal Window containing a few form fields
4. Begin filling out form fields. Whenever the Store happens to reload, focus will be stolen. **THIS IS THE PROBLEM**

Any input would be great, please ask if any additional information or screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried suspendevents and resume events before the store.sync()?  Not obvious to me that would work but it's worth trying

Comment: @PeterKellner I'm not calling store.sync(), but yes I've tried suspending/resuming events. The solution for me ended up being patching to 4.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up patching to 4.2.1 which has solved my issue, LoadMasks are now properly bound to a view and do not take precedence over modal windows, and tooltips no longer steal focus.

Comment: nice!  I'm curious if you posted on the Sencha Forum.  They often will take posts like your and turn them into feature requests/bugs right from your forum post.  This sounds like one that should be there.